# android scroll list with smooth resizing boundary elements

Tags: android, scroll

I need list of items in screen, which consists with set of buttons, some of buttons are displayed and some are hidden. When user scrolls ListView up then top item must compress smoothly  until it disappear  and on the bottom the new item must smoothly growing up to normal sizes. When user scrolls  ListView down then bottom item must compress smoothly  until it disappear and on the top the new item must smoothly growing up to normal sizes. It seems  listView + OnScrollListener are not suitable for these purposes. Could You advise me other approaches?

[image]

Comment: Take a look at this project https://github.com/davidschreiber/FancyCoverFlow.

Comment: This might help you https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations